# how change result

Tags: c#

I try to create messeneger for my company where We have DNS (every pc has static ip and name of PC). All works by insert,select(mysql). I want to send group message where I choose name of PC and IP address

here is code for computer information

```
 {
        IPHostEntry he;
        string myip = "";
        he = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in he.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                myip = ip.ToString();
            }


        }
        label1.Text = myip;
    }

    string pc = System.Environment.MachineName;
```

here I want to select group (skupina) of computers and insert to the messages (nrp)

```
 using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection("Server=10.7.18.35;Database=OitDB;Uid=martin;Pwd=;"))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT namepc FROM skupina where nazovskup= 'mojask' ", cnn); 
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "skupina");

            List<string> skName = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["skupina"].Rows)
            {

                skName.Add(row["namepc"].ToString());
                string constring = "Server=10.7.18.35;Database=OitDB;Uid=martin;Pwd=;";
                var Query = "INSERT INTO OitDB.skup(uzivatel)VALUES(@name)";
                MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
                MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDatabase);
                cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = string.Join("",skName.ToArray());
                MySqlDataReader myReader;


                try
                {
                    conDatabase.Open();
                    myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
                    MessageBox.Show("Správa odoslaná!");
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

but now I have result in mysql like:

```
row1-message1-pc1 
row2-message1-pc1,pc2 
row3-message1-pc1,pc2,pc3

and I want to:

row1-message1-pc1
row2-message1-pc2
row3-message1-pc3
```

Have you any idea?

Comment: Well at the moment, your `SELECT` isn't ordered... do you mind which row ends up with which `rowX=...` part? Are you just trying to transform a list `{ "x", "y", "z" }` into a list `{ "row1=x", "row2=y", "row3=z" }`? Because if so, the MySQL part is pretty irrelevant...

Comment: Yes I want just transform list to `{ "row1=x", "row2=y", "row3=z" }` how can I remove MySQL part?

Comment: By giving a short but complete example which *just* starts with a `List<string>`. You can populate that without any database access... It's very important to be able to narrow down a problem to just what's relevant.

Comment: Edit question. How can I give 3 rows from first table to list and next give to the second table?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "give 3 rows" but you appear to have removed the mysql tag but done nothing else. You should be putting together a [mcve] which doesn't need *anything* to do with mysql.

Comment: I want to select data from skupina table with n rows and insert to table skup n times. When I have 3 rows in skupina table I want insert to skup table 3 times

Comment: Okay, so why are you building up the list? Surely you just need to insert with the *current* row... I don't see why you'd want to insert 1 value in the first row, 2 values in the second row, 3 values in the third row etc.

Comment: This is only test code. I have project where I need select rows from first table and insert to second table.

Comment: Well it sounds like it's test code that doesn't properly explain what you're trying to achieve. You still haven't explained why you're adding to a list in the loop, and basically including all the values you've seen so far in each new row. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints and put *much* more effort into clearly explaining what you're trying to achieve and what you're stuck on.

Comment: You can imagine som like messenger where post message to namePC. And if I want send message to group (table skupina) then I need insert all rows from table skupina and text message to table skup. Explain message1-pc1,message1-pc2,message1-pc3, next I select messages only for specific PC

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you're doing what you're doing, and you need to give a *lot* more thought to being clear - *edit your question* to make it clear. Don't just add comments - edit...

Comment: I see you're back to inviting SQL injection attacks. *Don't do that*. Use parameterized SQL, always. And you *still* haven't explained why you've got the code you've already got, building up a list. Why aren't you just setting the parameter value to `row["namepc"]`? Do you understand why you're getting the result you're currently getting? Do you understand the code you've currently got?

Comment: OK. All I'll change to parameterized SQL. Now I don't undestand, how can I setting the parameter value to `row["namepc"]`? Yes I understand my code (by himself), but I'm only beginner in C# and I need help with my problem.

Comment: Um, you say `cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row["namepc"]`... If you understand your own code, you should be able to explain why you're building up a list and on each iteration of insertion joining *all* the values so far. So far you haven't explained that, despite me asking several times.

Comment: Edit question. I change all to parameterized sql, but when I build project and insert data messagebox wrote: column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: No it was my mistake. All work's good. Thank you for everithing!

Comment: Well now the code you've presented wouldn't give the result you're claiming. Is there anything you still want to know? If not, you could either edit the question to be a lot clearer, and answer it yourself, or delete the question.

Comment: Nope, you really haven't. You've still got code which wouldn't give the results you've claimed, and it's still unclear whether the hints I've given you so far have actually fixed the issue. You really, really should read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints very carefully, to learn how to write a good question.

Answer (score 0):

this is functional code

```
using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection("Server=;Database=OitDB;Uid=martin;Pwd=;"))
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT namepc FROM skupina where nazovskup= 'mojask' ", cnn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "skupina");

        List<string> skName = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["skupina"].Rows)
        {

            skName.Add(row["namepc"].ToString());
            string constring = "Server=;Database=OitDB;Uid=martin;Pwd=;";
            var Query = "INSERT INTO OitDB.nrp(id,pc,ip,komu,datum,predmet,sprava,skupina)VALUES(@id,@pc,@ip,@komu,@cas,@predmet,@sprava,@name)";
            MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDatabase);

            cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idtxt.Text);
            cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pc", pc);
            cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", label1.Text);
            cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@komu", comboBox1.Text);
            cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cas", cas);
            cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@predmet", textBox1.Text);
            cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sprava", pisat.Text);
            cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row["namepc"];
            MySqlDataReader myReader;


            try
            {
                conDatabase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
                MessageBox.Show("Správa odoslaná!");
                while (myReader.Read())
                {

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
        }
```

Comment: That's the code in the question, isn't it? If it's not, which bit is the difference?